# PHP return to previous page

Tags: php, categories, catalog

I've created a product catalogue with category - subcategory - individual product page. I pass a $category to the individual product page. This page lists various details about the item, including which category the item belongs to. Since the $category variable is already set, I thought `<a href="category.php?category=$category">Return to previous category</a>` would be enough to return it to the subcategory page but it doesn't, part of the category.php that handles this looks like this.

**EDIT: Full code**

### product_list.php

```
    <?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ?>

    <?php
    include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <meta name="Description" content="Lightweight aluminum boat docks, lifts, and accessories" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="Aluminum boat dock ladder lift water wheels" />
    <script src="scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <title>Products</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    </style>
    <body>
    <div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
    <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15">
      <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="center"><table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle"><p>Aluminum Docks</p>
            <p><a href="category.php?category=Aluminum_Docks"><img src="inventory_images/aluminum docks/PN99002-6_24x4_PKG_LG.jpg" width="25%" height="64"/></a></p></td>
          <td align="center"><p>Floating Docks</p>
            <p><a href="category.php?category=Floating_Dock"><img src="inventory_images/floating dock/100225279.jpg" width="25%" height="64"/></a></p></td>
          <td align="center"><p>Frame Docks</p>
            <p><a href="category.php?category=Frame_Dock"><img src="inventory_images/frame dock/frameDock.jpg" width="25%" height="64" alt="Frame Dock" /></a></a></p></td>
          <td align="center"><p>Pipe Docks</p>
            <p><a href="category.php?category=Pipe_Dock"><img src="inventory_images/pipe dock/PN99002_16X4_SECTION_LG.jpg" width="25%" height="64" alt="Pipe Dock" /></a></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><p>Boat Lifts</p>
            <p><a href="category.php?category=Boat_Lifts"><img src="inventory_images/boat lifts/GM1060_LG.jpg" width="25%" height="64" alt="Boat Lift" /></a></p></td>
          <td align="center"><p>Boat Lift Accessories</p>
            <p><a href="category.php?category=Boat_Lift_Accessories"><img src="inventory_images/boat lift acceessories/canopy_lg (1).png" width="25%" height="64" alt="Boat Lift Accessory" /></a></p></td>
          <td align="center"><p>Rollers &amp; Caddies</p>
            <p><a href="category.php?category=Rollers_and_Caddies"><img src="inventory_images/rollers and caddies/caddy270 (1).jpg"width="25%" height="64" alt="Caddy" /></a></p></td>
          <td align="center"><p>Accessories</p>
            <p><a href="category.php?category=Accessories"><img src="inventory_images/accessorries/2step_LG.png" width="25%" height="64" alt="Accessory" /></a></p></td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

**category.php**
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>

    <?php 
    // Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $category=$_GET['category'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='$category' LIMIT 50");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        $dynamicList="";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
                 $id = $row["id"];
                 $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                 $price = $row["price"];
                 $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
                 $dynamicList .= '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
            <tr>
              <td width="17%" valign="top"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '" target="target_product"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="100" height="64" border="1" /></a></td>
              <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
                $' . $price . '<br />
                <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product Details</a></td>
            </tr>
          </table>';
        }
    } else {
        $dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <meta name="Description" content="Lightweight aluminum boat docks, lifts, and accessories" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="Aluminum boat dock ladder lift water wheels" />
    <script src="scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <title><?php echo $category; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    </style>
    <body>
    <div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
    <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
    <div align="left">
      <p><?php echo $dynamicList;?>
      </p>
      <div id="target_product"></div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

**product.php**

    <?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ?>

    <?php
    include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
    session_start();
    //Check to see if the URL variable is set and exists in the database
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_GET['id']);
        // Use this variable to see if the id exists, if yesthen get the product
        // details, if no then exit the script and give message why.
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id ='$id' LIMIT 1");
        $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
        if ($productCount > 0) {
        // Get all product details  
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
                 $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                 $price = $row["price"];
                 $details = $row["details"];
                 $quantity = $row["quantity_in_stock"];
                 $category = $row["category"];
                 $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
          }
        }else{
            echo "That item does not exist.";
        exit();
        }
    }else{
        echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
        exit();
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <meta name="Description" content="Lightweight aluminum boat docks, lifts, and accessories" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="Aluminum boat dock ladder lift water wheels" />
    <script src="scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <title><?php echo $product_name; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    </style>
    <body>
    <div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
    <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15">
      <tr>
      <td width="20%" valign="top" ><img src="inventory_images/<?php echo $id;?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" />
      <td width="80%" valign="top"> <h3><?php echo $product_name; ?></h3>
      <p>$<?php echo $price; ?><br/>
      <?php echo $category; ?>
      <br/>
      <?php echo $details; ?><br/>
      <?php echo $quantity;?>


      <p><a href="product_list.php?category=$category">Return to previous category</a></p>  
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you explain, what goes wrong? Also, your $category-variable is completely unsecured and leaves your system wide open for injection attacks.

Comment: There's obviously more to that script or it's not the right script. Otherwise you are right, it would work.

Comment: I just made an edit showing my full code. It's not live, and I haven't done any tightening to the security yet as I'm just learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all data that was containing your previous page, use SESSION superglobal for this purpose.

Comment: I tried storing the category in my Session variable like this: $_SESSION['previous'] = $_GET['category'];
Then I tried creating a link like this:<a href="category.php?category=<?php echo $_SESSION['previous'];?>"> but the address is only redirecting to category.php?category=, it's not appending it with the SESSION variable.

Comment: you need to start session on all pages that you use session superglobal, that way you can use these settings

Comment: in category.php you need to start `session_start()`, and then use `$_SESSION['previous'] = $_GET['category']` (GET superglobal is used when you need to get value from Uri). Then in product.php you also start session, and then access `$_SESSION['previous']` as you need it. Hope this helps.